# How to MapRoute to a sub controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a file, AdminController.cs, that currently holds the controllers for every action in the admin section of my site. Obviously, this is getting huge, and I'd like to delegate control to a different controller for each application.

For instance:

`www.mysite.com/Admin/Car` currently looks to AdminController.cs to decide what to do. So when a user adds a car, there is an ActionResult in AdminController.cs called AddCar(). I would like this instead to look to `CarController.cs` to find AddCar().

So I after some research, I added this to my RouteConfig file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "/Admin/Car"
    url: "{parent}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { parent = "Admin", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { controller = "Car"}
);
```

I commented out the ActionResults related to 'Car' in AdminController, and added them to CarController.

However, I'm getting "The resource cannot be found." when I navigate to `www.mysite.com/Admin/Car`.

How can I use a different controller, but with the URL still in the `Admin` realm?

Comment: The standard way to do this would be to use Areas. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could add a controller action 'Car' to the Admin controller which redirects to the relevant action in the Car controller. But, Areas are probably what you want.